# Problem with state update in function handle

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

everybody,
i currently have the problem that the state in a handler function is not updated.

I have already tried to solve the problem using the useEffect hook, but unfortunately without success. Is my approach basically wrong or is it not possible with hooks?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Example = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  const handleNothing = () => {
    console.log("still old value", width);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setWidth(Math.random());
  };

  const handleBoth = () => {
    handleClick();
    handleNothing();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{width}</div>
      <button onClick={handleBoth}>Random value</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: Hi, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is `async` and will take some time to update the state.

You need to use dedicated [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to get updated state,

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(width)
},[width]) //Provide width as dependency so that your useEffect will only run when width changes
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kadu7c)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's exactly what I already did. But then I have to pass the width value to the second handler. Is there no way to use the state directly?

Comment: I think there is no way but this only. Initially, we have class-based components in that we have callback in setState, but now for functional component, they have removed the callback concept and added a dedicated hook called `useEffect`